# Receber valor de array json para string - Java

Tags: java, json

Olá,

Não tenho tanto conhecimento em Json e estou com um problema e não encontrei solução exata dele na comunidade.

Tenho o seguinte formato no arquivo json:

```
     {
    "name" : "ProductName",
    "description" : "description",
    "alternate": [
      {"type": "prodType", "element": "prodElement"}
    ]

  },
```

O que eu preciso e não consigo:

Pegar dentro do 'alternate' o valor 'prodType' e armazená-lo em uma string e fazer o mesmo com o valor 'prodElement'.

Meu arquivo Gson está assim:

```
  @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

  @SerializedName("description")
    public String description;

  @SerializedName("alternate")
    public List alternate;
```

Eu não declarei o 'Type' e o 'Element' pois não sei se deveria e como faria.

Fiz os getters e os setters, porém ele só retorna a linha inteira:

```
{"type": "prodType", "element": "prodElement"}
```

Alguém sabe como prosseguir?

Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua definição do objeto está errada. *Alternate* é uma coleção de objetos com dois campos: "type" e "element". A seguinte definição de classes representa os dados do json informado:

```
public class MeusDados {
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public List<Alternate> alternate;
}

public class Alternate {
    public String type;
    public String element;
}
```

Você pode testar com o código abaixo:

```
String json = "{\"name\":\"ProductName\",\"description\":\"description\",\"alternate\":[{\"type\":\"prodType\",\"element\":\"prodElement\"}]}";

Gson gson = new Gson();
MeusDados dados = gson.fromJson(json, MeusDados.class);
if (dados.alternate.get(0).element.equals("prodElement")) {
    // entrará aqui!!!
}
```

O primeiro elemento da `List` "alternate" contém os dados que você deseja inspecionar. Note que se você tiver acesso à rotina que gera esse json e esse campo `alternate` não for um array, mas sim sempre um único objeto, modifique seu json para:

```
{
    "name" : "ProductName",
    "description" : "description",
    "alternate": {
        "type": "prodType", 
        "element": "prodElement"
    }
},
```

E mude a definição da classe MeusDados (ou outro nome que vier a dar para ela) para:

```
public class MeusDados {
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public Alternate alternate;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso mesmo que eu estava fazendo de errado. Eu já havia visto alguns exemplos um pouco parecidos mas não tinha entendido muito bem, obrigado, você quebrou um galho!